# Oracle Pipelined Function with Joins

Tags: oracle11g, left-join, pipelined-function

Here is the creation of my two types needed for the Pipelined function to work:

```
create or replace type               RIS_CPU as object (
NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), COMPUTER_NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), PERCENT_PROCESSOR_TIME NUMBER,
REGION VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), ENVIRONMENT VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), GB_Date DATE, 
DESCRIPTIVE_NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), APPLICATION VARCHAR2(255 BYTE));  

create or replace type RISSERVERCPUTABLE as table of MIIMonitoring.RIS_CPU;
```

This is the section that is causing my error.  I do not really know how to approach creating 2 values to loop through for my cursor.  Please help.

```
create or replace FUNCTION DUNDAS_FUNCTION_RIS_SERVER_CPU
(
SMOOTHV IN NUMBER, DAYSV IN NUMBER, SERVERV IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN RISSERVERCPUTABLE PIPELINED 
AS 
CURSOR DUNDAS_CURSOR2 IS 

SELECT JOI.NAME, JOI.COMPUTER_NAME, JOI.PERCENT_PROCESSOR_TIME, JOI.REGION,
JOI.ENVIRONMENT, JOI.GB_Date, N.DESCRIPTIVE_NAME, N.APPLICATION
FROM
(SELECT NAME, COMPUTER_NAME, TRUNC(AVG(PERCENT_PROCESSOR_TIME)+.5,0) PERCENT_PROCESSOR_TIME,
REGION, ENVIRONMENT,
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT,'MI'))/SMOOTHV,0)*SMOOTHV||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS GB_Date
FROM APP_PROCESSOR 
WHERE DT > = sysdate - DAYSV
AND NAME = '_Total'
AND COMPUTER_NAME = SERVERV
GROUP BY NAME, COMPUTER_NAME, REGION, ENVIRONMENT,
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:')||TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT,'MI'))/SMOOTHV,0)*SMOOTHV||':00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))JOI
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT SERVER_NAME, DESCRIPTIVE_NAME, APPLICATION
FROM SERVERS_TRANSLATION_TABLE) N
ON JOI.COMPUTER_NAME = N.SERVER_NAME;

DUNDASRECORD1 "MIIMONITORING"."APP_PROCESSOR"%rowtype;
DUNDASRECORD2 "MIIMONITORING"."SERVERS_TRANSLATION_TABLE"%rowtype;

BEGIN
OPEN DUNDAS_FUNCTION_RIS_SERVER_CPU.DUNDAS_CURSOR2;

LOOP
fetch DUNDAS_CURSOR2 into DUNDASRECORD1;
exit when (DUNDAS_CURSOR2%notfound);
fetch DUNDAS_CURSOR2 into DUNDASRECORD2;
exit when (DUNDAS_CURSOR2%notfound);

pipe row (RIS_CPU(
DUNDASRECORD1.NAME, DUNDASRECORD1.COMPUTER_NAME, DUNDASRECORD1.PERCENT_PROCESSOR_TIME, 
DUNDASRECORD1.REGION, DUNDASRECORD1.ENVIRONMENT, 
DUNDASRECORD1.GB_DATE, DUNDASRECORD2.DESCRIPTIVE_NAME, DUNDASRECORD2.APPLICATION)
);
END LOOP;
CLOSE DUNDAS_CURSOR2;
RETURN;
END DUNDAS_FUNCTION_RIS_SERVER_CPU;
```

Right now this returns the error:

```
FUNCTION DUNDAS_FUNCTION_RIS_SERVER_CPU compiled
Errors: check compiler log
FUNCTION DUNDAS_FUNCTION_RIS_SERVER_CPU compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: Did you check the compiler log (where, apparently, the *actual* error message is?

Comment: You can use `show errors`, or query the `user_errors` view, to see the actual problem. It looks wrong for you to be doing two fetches from one cursor into two variables declared differently - presumably the two rowtypes are not identical. Not sure if you think you can fetch the first few columns into one rowtype variable and the rest of the columsn *from the same row in the resultset* into a different variable. That isn't how it works. You'd be better off with the other type of cursor loop.